# How to localize Entity Table column name in DevExpress

Tags: .net, angular, devexpress, reporting

I wanted to know how to localize the names of the tables and the names of the columns in the web version (Angular) of Dev Express?
Thanks
[image]

```
Platform :Angular Reporting
Product: Reporting for Angular
Framework / Specific :.NET Core
Build: 21.2.14
Operating System: Windows Server 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the database schema provider and return your custom table/stored procedure/column names in your own implementation of the IDBSchemaProvider interface. See the following tutorial: [SQL Database - Customize the Schema](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/400567/web-reporting/asp-net-core-reporting/end-user-report-designer-in-asp-net-applications/use-data-sources-and-connections/sql-database-customize-the-schema).